# "Нести околесицу"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение фразеологизма "нести околесицу"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словарь Фасмера:
ОколеЁсина.  Ближайшая этимология: "колея на повороте", ОколеЁсица, ОколеЁсить "нести вздор, говорить вокруг да около", первонач. "объезжать". От О- и Колесоґ; см. Мi. ЕW 124. Страницы: 3,129

Околесину нести
Околесину нести (околесѝть — околесную: не прямо, а путая, длинно и безтолково говорить).
Ср. Предводителишка вретъ и несетъ свою околесную, а дурачье мужичье стоятъ и слушаютъ.(http://slovari.yandex.ru/)

Comment: У вас плохо воспроизвелось. Околе'сина. Ё там нету.

Comment: ОКОЛЕ́СИЦА, -ы и ОКОЛЁСИЦА, -ы, жен. (разг.). Бессмыслица, вздор. Нести околесицу. (Словарь Ожегова).

ОКОЛЁСИЦА, околёсицы, мн. нет, ж. (разг. фам.). вздор, бессмыслица. (Ушаков).
околёсина-    ж. разг.-сниж.
    Глупые, пустые разговоры; бессмыслица, вздор, околесица. (Словарь Ефремовой). 
И у Фасмера точно так, как передала Екатерина.