# Что такое "околесица"?

Tags: этимология

Искала поиском, вроде, такого вопроса не было. Подскажите, пожалуйста, от чего произошло слово "околесица" и почему оно означает бред, ерунду?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повтор вопроса.

["Нести околесицу"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6057/)

Но коли уж дан другой ответ...

Околесица, первоначально "околесина"   - выбоина на дороге. От коло - круг, отсюда же околица.
Применительно к языку означает свернуть с пути (разговора), говорить вокруг да ***около***.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день!
От слова околить (околесить) - очистить бревно от коры. Бревно это затем будет использовано для строительных нужд, а та вся кора, которая осталось после околесия - это мусор, который подлежит утилизации на костре или  выбрасыванию на свалку. 
  Иными словами, выражение "нести околесицу" буквально можно перевести как "производить словесный мусор".

Comment: А откуда тогда само "околить"?  
Никогда не сталкивался с подобным значением.
Оно есть у Даля как областное, но сомнительно, тем более что Даль предполагает связь с "оголить" - совершенно невозможное. 

Я бы скорее сказал, что "околить" - огораживать (кругом).

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю. Коло = круг. Околить = округлить. Но есть и другой вариант. Бревно "окоряют", когда снимают кору. В какой-то области "окорить" вполне могло превратиться в "околить".